# React project - spread operator in node module unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

I'm building a react application, and I'm importing a node module which uses the spread operator `...` and I'm getting an error "Module parse failed: Unexpected token (100:6)" at this operator. How can I get this to work?

Thanks

Comment: Did you install from `create-react-app` or build from scratch? Did you install babel to support newer ES6 syntax?

Comment: Which module? What's the exact error message and what is on line 100, column 6? (BTW ... is not an operator, but *syntax*)

Comment: https://babeljs.io. If you create app from `create-react-app`, it will be installed internally. If not, you must install it to support new syntax

Comment: I used create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

The create-react-app cli has already bundled this ES2015 feature.
Older babel does not support this and needs to be installed separately

Now assuming you setup your react manually and not using the create-react-app.
You can set up this by installing  the package 
[babel-plugin-transform-es2015-spread](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-spread) 
or
[babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread](http://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread/)

Here is the step to work with this

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-es2015-spread
```

Now open your .babelrc and declare the plugin

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-es2015-spread"]
}
```

Possible Duplicate : [Spread Operator not working for Redux/ES6 based sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310830/spread-operator-not-working-for-redux-es6-based-sample)

Comment: I've already done all that, and it works for _my_ code, but not a specific npm package I have imported

Comment: @picklechips same problem here... have you managed to resolve this issue in the end?

Comment: @mjsarfatti what about you, any luck? I'm having this problem too.

Comment: @Raven I'm sorry I have no idea what I did in the end, it was too long ago :/